# How to retrieve ItemAttachment bytes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I want to download the bytes of an attachment to an email that is itself an email using Microsoft Graph.

My only option at the moment appears to be to use the Get `ItemAttachment` method on the API that looks like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myAccount/messages/{messageId}/attac
hments/{attachmentId}?$expand=microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item
```

and the returned JSON has an `item` node with this value:

```json
{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.message",
  "id": "",
  "createdDateTime": "2018-01-18T01:51:02Z",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-01-18T01:50:36Z",
  "receivedDateTime": "2018-01-18T00:21:35Z",
  "sentDateTime": "2018-01-18T00:21:48Z",
  "hasAttachments": true,
  "internetMessageId":
    "<2097905212.0.1516234908909.JavaMail.root@dszsarapps01r>",
  "subject": "blah",
  "importance": "normal",
  "conversationId":
    "AAQkADQ3YjdiNWUxLTBmYWQtNDMwYy04YzDFjNgAQAFM3Iqwf0gRHqfUyw2AniAQ=",
  "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
  "isRead": true,
  "isDraft": false,
  "webLink":
    "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADQ3YjdiNWUxLTOWQ4NDFjNgAAAA%3D%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "text",
    "content": "some content"
  },
  "sender": {
    "emailAddress": {
      "name": "me@somewhere",
      "address": "me@somewhere"
    }
  },
  "from": {
    "emailAddress": {
      "name": "boo@there",
      "address": "boo@there"
    }
  },
  "toRecipients": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "name": "him@where",
        "address": "him@where"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the presence of attachments is indicated by the `hasAttachments` field but the attachments are not visible in the JSON.

I suspect that nested attachments/emails (possibly to many levels) are not supported by Graph API but even if it were it would be risky and time-consuming trying to reconstruct the original bytes of the `.eml` attachment from JSON.

I would rather treat the `ItemAttachment` as a `FileAttachment` and download its bytes. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Thanks for taking  the trouble to edit @Marc LaFleur but you have been a bit strong. I'll fix. too many levels -> to many levels. email -> eml

Comment: Ah! I didn't catch that you were looking for the raw MIME from an attached item. I'm afraid that currently, it isn't possible to retrieve the raw message (`.eml`). I know it has been heavily considered but no actual ETA at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I must admit this took me a while to figure out but here it is.

Get your email list
you should include: -
HasAttachments
Attachments

and also configure it .Expand("attachments")

iterate around email messages
if email.hasattachment
iterate around the attachments{

Attachment content = await MSGraphServiceClient.Me.Messages[email.Id].Attachments[fileAttachment.Id].Request().GetAsync();

// this is the important bit which took me awhile to work out
byte[] file = ((FileAttachment)content).ContentBytes;

}
I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I would rather treat the ItemAttachment as a FileAttachment and download its bytes. Does anyone know how to do this?

Based on my test, you mentioned Rest API the returned json should be the following format. And you could easily get the **contentBytes**.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{messageid}/attachments/{attachmentId}?$expand=microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item
```

I test it with [graph-explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('userId')/messages('messiageid')/attachments/$entity",
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
    "id": "AAMkAGY3ZjQxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6A=",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-02-08T09:58:12Z",
    "name": "xxx.PNG",
    "contentType": "image/png",
    "size": 8419,
    "isInline": false,
    "contentId": null,
    "contentLocation": null,
    "contentBytes": "iVBORw0KGgoxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Graph returns an attachment as either a FileAttachment, ItemAttachment or ReferenceAttachment. I think you are showing me the result of an attachment that is a FileAttachment and is not an embedded email (ItemAttachment). Is that the case? The return from an ItemAttachment does not include contentBytes and that is consistent with the API documentation on this.